# ORA-01465: invalid hex number or data mismatch error using hibernate jpa and oracle in coalesce

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, coalesce

In java spring boot when I am using coalesce function for search query with oracle backend, null values are not handled properly. using jpql it either gives me RAW-- ORA-01465: invalid hex number or data mismatch error, like expected binary got integer

Comment: I want to know solution to the above problem.

Comment: @Query("select t from SearchFilter t where "
            + "COALESCE(?1, COALESCE( t.aId ,0)) = COALESCE( t.aId ,0) AND "
            + "COALESCE(?2, COALESCE(t.cId,'a')) = COALESCE(t.cId,'a') AND "
            + "COALESCE(?3, COALESCE(t.assignTo,'a')) = COALESCE(t.assignTo,'a'))")
List<SearchFilter> findsearchresult(Integer aid, String cid, String assignedTo);    I am trying above query and getting invalid hex number as the run time error

Comment: Please do not add code in comments. Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the documentation of [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617)

The usage is

> COALESCE (expr1, expr2, ..., exprn)

and not nested as in your example

```
COALESCE (expr1, COALESCE (expr2,expr3))
```

Check the data type of the bind parameters and referenced database columns.
It seems that some of them are not `VARCHAR` (possible numeric), which is in conflict with the value of `'a'`

If you want to handle all expressions in the `COALESCE` as character strings (which I deduce from teh construction `COALESCE(t.cId,'a')`), you must excplicitely convert the non-strings using `TO_CHAR`.

Basically you need, all expressions in the `COALESCE` in the same datatype or at least able to convert to the datatype, that is defined with the first parameter.

Comment: even if I remove non string parameters from the query. it still runs into invalid hex number. instead of passing parameters from the method if i set its value directly inside query null. it gives right result.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the datatype of the parameters 1-3 (i.e how they are defined with  setXxxxx). Add datatype of all relevant database columns (e.g.  t.aId). The problem is very probably in teh fact, that those two datatype are not compatible,

Comment: @Query("select t from SearchFilter t where " + "COALESCE(?1, COALESCE( t.aId ,0)) = COALESCE( t.aId ,0) AND " + "COALESCE(?2, COALESCE(t.cId,'a')) = COALESCE(t.cId,'a') AND " + "COALESCE(?3, COALESCE(t.assignTo,'a')) = COALESCE(t.assignTo,'a'))") List<SearchFilter> findsearchresult(Integer aid, String cid, String assignedTo);

t.aId is number in the database and integer in java
t.cId is varchar2 in the database and string in java
t.assignTo is varchar2 in the database and string in java


to_char didnt solve the problem. it gives me error, expected number got char

Comment: @pranalinarkar please in the **first place modify your query using the flat form of `COALESCE (expr1, expr2, ..., exprn)`** this is definitively not the same as the nested form you use. Than **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)** your question with the additional information - **do not used comments to post code**.

Comment: I have used nested coalesce for search filter inorder to make the right side 1=1